# Delta formula for FX vanilla option

Tags: options, delta

What value do you use for annual dividend yield? 
It does not apply in case of FX.

Answer (score 1):

When pricing FX options, the underlying is the spot or forward exchange rate.

The foreign currency is analogous to a stock where the owner of the foreign currency receives a "dividend yield" equal to the risk-free rate in the foreign currency.